# Non-binary tree

Tags: c, pointers, tree

I have to create a tree that can have up to *n* subnodes for each node (i.e its not a binary tree).
How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for n-ary trees - http://oopweb.com/Algorithms/Documents/PLDS210/Volume/n_ary_trees.html
The creation should be pretty simple from the information in this and other links (in google).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having something like this:

```
Node* left;
Node* right;
```

which you would normally do for a binary tree, you can do something like:

```
Node** children;
int size;
```

then `malloc` the appropriate size for the number of pointers.

Comment: @all
thanks for the help
i developed a code for n number of nodes with hepl of ur info

Answer (score 0):

GLib provides an [implementation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.6/glib-N-ary-Trees.html) of N-ary trees. If you can't use glib you should look for another library that suits your needs or roll your own N-ary tree. In a simple version a node would contain a linked list or array with pointers to further nodes.